# German equivalents of the English idiom “Don't come crawling/running back to me!”

Tags: phrase-request

In conversation with my friend, I said jokingly:

> Aber **komm** nur nicht **heulend** bei mir **angekrochen**, wenn du ...

to express the idea of:

> Don't come crawling/running back to me when you ...
>
> Don't come crying to me when you ...

In English, you use the expression "Don't come crawling/running back to me (when ...)" tauntingly, half expecting that someone who is putting on a tough-guy act, turning a deaf ear to friendly advice etc will wake up to an unpleasant reality sooner or later and regret the day they spurned the opportunities, the offers of help etc.

Q1. Am I correct in assuming that the main clause should end with the past participle of a verb (such as ***angekrochen***, ***angerannt***, ***angelaufen***) – not with the present participle in keeping with the English wording "crawling/running"?

Q2. I wonder if the past participle at the end has to be a verb with the prefix "**an**-"?

Q3. Which preposition  is more common to use here: "**bei** mir" or "**zu** mir"?

More importantly, are there some other idiomatic expressions to convey this idea?

Comment: Only a third of an answer: You would not use any preposition with angekrochen: Komm ja nicht angekrochen, wenn das schief geht!

Comment: *Komm ja nicht zu mir gekrochen, wenn …* – But this is all very unfriendly and shouldn't be used at all. Actually, you depict the German picture of someone brown-nosing, *Arschkriecherei*, which literally means *to crawl up someone's ass*. *Crawling* to someone in an idiomatic expression is very, very, very ill.

Comment: @Janka, I'm not with you. There's no more behind-the-words-notion in *kriechen* in German than is in *to crawl* in English (which doesn't mean I would use it in any of both languages, with that part I completely agree).

Answer (score 2):

Q3: German would very probably use the *dativus ethicus* for such a sentence instead of the "to me" preposition construct your English examples use, so

> Komm mir nicht angekrochen, wenn du ...
>
> Komm mir nicht angerannt, wenn du ...

Q2, Q1: Yes

Most native speakers would, however, decorate the sentences with some adverbs and particles to stress both the demand [*bloß, ja* = particles] and the return, [*wieder* = adverb] so

> Komm mir bloß nicht wieder angekrochen, wenn du ...
>
> Komm mir ja nicht wieder angekrochen, wenn du ...
>
> Komm mir bloß nicht wieder angerannt, wenn du ...
>
> Komm mir ja nicht wieder angerannt, wenn du ...

Comment: ad Q2: *Komm mir ja nicht **zurück**gekrochen, wenn du ...*

Comment: Zurückgekrochen sounds quite odd to me, being from the nothern part of Germany. Might be a regional thing.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast *zurückgekrochen* would fit if we assume a relationship existed between the persons that was broken by one of them - In all other possible contexts, I don't see it as appropriate. Unfortunately, the question doesn't provide more context.

Comment: The question explicitly was about *»Don't come crawling/running **back** to me!«* I think this is context enough to say that *zurückkriechen* fits better than *ankriechen*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast See my comment to your answer. I think *zurückkriechen* implies something that is not in the English sentence

Comment: @tofro: *»Zurückgekrochen«* only assumes, that the person that is crawling back was away, i.e. this person was just at another place. There is no reason to assume that a relationship was broken.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast That is what it implies to me, I can't help it - I would never use that in any other context than the mentioned. If you insist to translate the "back" of the original sentence, use *wieder*.

Comment: Also to @HubertSchölnast Yes, the use of Dative... it didn't come to mind back there for some reason. Anyway, do you find my original phrasing unnatural -- something that native speakers are unlikely to come up with?

Answer (score 2):

### Q1

Yes, it must be *Partizip Perfekt*.
*Partizip Präsens* (*»ankriechend«*) would be wrong.

---

### Q2

No, also *»zurück-«* is possible:

> Aber komm nur nicht heulend zu mir **zurückgekrochen,** wenn du ...

---

### Q3

If the prefix of the verb is *»an-«*, then you are talking about arriving at a place, and so the preposition *»bei«* fits better. But if you use the prefix *»zurück-«*, then you are talking about moving in a direction, and then it should be *»zu«*:

> Walter kommt **bei** Anna **an**gekrochen.
>   Walter kommt **zu** Anna **zurück**gekrochen.

---

But you can use a similar construction, that is a little bit more common among native speakers:

> Komm **mir** nicht angekrochen ...
>   Komm **mir** nicht zurückgekrochen ...

This *»mir«* is a special usage of dative case, that doesn't exist in English. It is one of the free dative usages (*free* = not bound to the verb) and is called *»Dativus ethicus«*. It stands for a person who is emotional involved into the action. Only a personal pronoun can be used for this kind of dative. So the example of Walter and Anna can not be transformed into this pattern.

Comment: *Walter kommt zu Anna zurückgekrochen* would somewhat automatically imply to me that Walter and Anna were a couple, Walter broke the relationship, and now wants her back. That doesn't fit the "good advice" case from the question, even if it is a more literal translation.

Comment: Warum glaubst du, Walter und Anna hätten eine Beziehung? Anna ist die Vorgesetzte von Walter, und Walter hat etwas gemacht, was er für richtig hielt. Er wurde deswegen von Anna gescholten. Walter war daraufhin unfreundlich zu Anna und verließ wütend ihr Büro, weil es sich ungerecht behandelt gefühlt hat. Später hat er aber erkannt, dass er tatsächlich einen Fehler gemacht hat, und dass die Schelte seiner Chefin gerechtfertigt war. Und jetzt kehrt er mit einem schlechten Gewissen ob seines Verhaltens ihr gegenüber zurück und möchte sich entschuldigen: Walter kommt zu Anna zurückgekrochen.

Comment: (Fortsetzung): Da gab es keine emotionale Bindung zwischen den beiden, die in die Brüche hätte gehen können. Es gibt nur die hierarchische Rang-Beziehung zwischen einem Angestellten und seiner Vorgesetzten, und die war zu keinem Zeitpunkt irgendwie außer Kraft gesetzt.

Comment: Für dein Beispiel würde ich eben "Komm mir bloß nicht wieder angekrochen" verwenden, aber in keinem Fall "zurückgekrochen" - Weil eben das für mich was anderes bedeutet. Wenn Walter und Anna  eine rein geschäftliche Beziehung hätten und Anna sagte, "komm zu mir zurück!" würde sich das für mich sehr, sehr komisch anhören, obwohl es, zugegebenermassen, wörtlich nur bedeutet, dass Anna möchte, das Walter zu ihr kommt. Das *Zurückkommen* und auch das *Zurückkriechen* ist eben vorbesetzt. Das Gleiche gälte übrigens auch für Anna und Martha, bevor mir hier jemand Sexismus unterstellt.